# Excel VBA Recipient Add based relevant cell

Tags: vba, excel

I took this code (http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com/using-excel-vba-to-set-up-task-reminders-in-outlook/) and added the strRecipient field myself. I am a total VBA noob and quite obviously, it doesn't work.  Can anyone offer a suggestion as to how I can get a Recipient section added that automatically feeds off of cell A4 for example?

Thanks

```
Option Explicit

Dim bWeStartedOutlook As Boolean

Function AddToTasks(strDate As String, strText As String, DaysOut As Integer, strRecipient As String) As Boolean
    ' Adds a task reminder to Outlook Tasks a specific number of days before the date specified
    ' Returns TRUE if successful
    ' Will not trigger OMG because no protected properties are accessed
    ' by Jimmy Pena, http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com, 10/30/2008
    '
    ' Usage:
    ' =AddToTasks("12/31/2008", "Something to remember", 30)
    ' or:
    ' =AddToTasks(A1, A2, A3)
    ' where A1 contains valid date, A2 contains task information, A3 contains number of days before A1 date to trigger task reminder
    '
    ' can also be used in VBA :
    'If AddToTasks("12/31/2008", "Christmas shopping", 30) Then
    '  MsgBox "ok!"
    'End If

Dim intDaysBack As Integer
Dim dteDate As Date
Dim olApp As Object ' Outlook.Application
Dim objTask As Object ' Outlook.TaskItem

' make sure all fields were filled in
If (Not IsDate(strDate)) Or (strText = "") Or (DaysOut <= 0) Or (strRecipient = "") Then
  AddToTasks = False
  GoTo ExitProc
End If

' We want the task reminder a certain number of days BEFORE the due date
' ex: if DaysOut = 120, then we want the due date to be -120 before the date specified
' we need to pass -120 to the NextBusinessDay function, so to go from 120 to -120,
' we subtract double the number (240) from the number provided (120).
' 120 - (120 * 2); 120 - 240 = -120

intDaysBack = DaysOut - (DaysOut * 2)

dteDate = CDate(strDate) + intDaysBack

On Error Resume Next
  Set olApp = GetOutlookApp
On Error GoTo 0

If Not olApp Is Nothing Then
  Set objTask = olApp.CreateItem(3)  ' task item

    With objTask
        .StartDate = dteDate
        .Subject = strText & ", due on: " & strDate
        .ReminderSet = True
        .Recipients.Add = strRecipient
        .Save
        .Assign
        .Send
    End With

Else
  AddToTasks = False
  GoTo ExitProc
End If

' if we got this far, it must have worked
AddToTasks = True

ExitProc:
If bWeStartedOutlook Then
  olApp.Quit
End If
Set olApp = Nothing
Set objTask = Nothing
End Function

Function GetOutlookApp() As Object

On Error Resume Next
  Set GetOutlookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set GetOutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    bWeStartedOutlook = True
  End If
On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Comment: How are you calling this function? Is this a button? Is the recipient in `A4` always going to be in that cell or will the cell your referring change? As you are not returning anything back to your calling procedure would it not make more sense to make this a subroutine rather than a function?

Comment: Right now I am calling it with a formula (=AddToTasks(A1,A2,A3,A4)), eventually it will likely be a button.  The cell I will be referencing will change though.

Answer (score 0):

add the following before `With objTask`

```
strRecipient = Sheets("sheet name here").Range("A4").Value
```

```
strRecipient = Sheets("sheet name here").Range("A4").Value
With objTask
    .startdate = dteDate
    .CC = strRecipient
    .Subject = strText & ", due on: " & strDate
    .ReminderSet = True
    .Save
    .Assign
    .Send
End With
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve my issue, as it is still giving me the same #VALUE! error.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: @tgaraffa have changed `sheet name`?

Comment: Hi @Omar   I did indeed. I am using this all on a dummy sheet for right now, so I changed it to "Sheet1" and still no luck.

Comment: how about change to `.CC = strRecipient`